# Calling a package method in a library in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using mandrill for a project in laravel.

I am able to send test emails out in the controller by adding the below code

```
$payload = array(
    'message' => array(
        'subject' => 'Transactional email via Mandrill',
        'html' => 'It works!',
        'from_email' => 'fromemail@example.com',
        'to' => array(array('email'=>'kwanghock@kwanghock.com.sg'))
    )
);

$response = Mandrill::request('messages/send', $payload);
```

However, when I move this chunk of code to a library, it gives me a

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Project\Email\Mandrill_lib\Mandrill' not found
```

I am using the package from https://github.com/doxxon/Laravel-Mandrill-Request

My library code as below

```
<?php namespace Project\Email\Mandrill_lib;

use LaravelMandrillRequest\Facades\LaravelMandrillRequestServiceProvider;
use LaravelMandrillRequest\Facades\MandrillRequest;

class MandrillEmail implements MandrillInterface {

    public function send($emails)
    {
        foreach($emails as $email)
        {
            $payload = array(
                'message' => array(
                    'subject' => 'Transactional email via Mandrill',
                    'html' => 'It works!',
                    'from_email' => 'fromemail@example.com',
                    'to' => array(array('email'=>'kwanghock@kwanghock.com.sg'))
                )
            );

            $response = Mandrill::request('messages/send', $payload);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "when I move to library" ? What is library ?

Comment: the libraries folder under the app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `user` Mandrill too:

```
use LaravelMandrillRequest\Facades\LaravelMandrillRequestServiceProvider;
use LaravelMandrillRequest\Facades\MandrillRequest;
use Mandrill; /// here!

class MandrillEmail implements MandrillInterface {
    ...
}
```

Or it will try to use it via your own namespace

```
Class 'Project\Email\Mandrill_lib\Mandrill' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

So then it is not referenced properly or not reckognized by composer.
First check you composer.json file and check that you have set path or namespace to that new library structure (new  relative to default app folders). Then do a composer dumpautoload. Note that controllers in app are namespaced by default.

Comment: in my composer.json autoload i added app/libraries and did a dumpautoload. It still gives the same error